# Add a startup application in the background in UbuntuGNOME 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, startup

I want transmission to startup when I login but would rather the window not pop up, I just want it to start minimized with it's app indicator. How can I add transmission to my startup applications but enable it to start in the background? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your Transmission after in background in two ways, either starting  `transmission-gtk` in minimized mode or using `transmission-daemon`

- If you want to start transmission window in background with its app
  indicator add following command in the **Startup Applications**

  `transmission-gtk --minimized`
- If you do not want to start transmission window but start your
  download when your computer starts, you can use `transmission-daemon`.

  Install it using `sudo apt-get install transmission-daemon`.

  It will start automatically when your computer starts.

  To stop it you can use
  `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! The daemon route is it!